# ledpar ignores \startstanzahook (not able to put extra space between stanzas)

Tags: ledmac, parallel

The ledmac/-par manual says that I may use `\startstanzahook` to get extra space between stanzas. But it works only in *normal* verses an not in parallel typsetting. The following example may give a better idea what I mean:

```
% XETEX-DOCUMENT
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{ledmac,ledpar}
    \maxchunks{100}
    \newcommand*{\startstanzahook}{\vspace{\baselineskip}}
\begin{document}
% works (vspace between stanzas):
\beginnumbering
\setstanzaindents{2,0,0}
\stanza 
    Non ego Caesareas, non arma virumque, & 
    sed chitaram plectrumque cano nec inutile numen 
\& 
\stanza 
    Doctus in Arcadiis vivebat musicus oris, & 
    clarus circa urbes et famae voce lyraeque.
\&
\endnumbering

% doesn't work (no vspace):
\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
    \beginnumbering
    \setstanzaindents{2,0,0}
    \stanza 
        Non ego Caesareas, non arma virumque, & 
        et lyricam poterit, nisi centum vocibus, artem? 
    \& 
    \stanza 
        Doctus in Arcadiis vivebat musicus oris, & 
        vicina quondam late celebratus in urbe 
    \& 
    \endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
    \beginnumbering
    \setstanzaindents{2,0,0}
    \stanza 
        Non ego Caesareas, non arma virumque, & 
        et lyricam poterit, nisi centum vocibus, artem? 
    \& 
    \stanza 
        Doctus in Arcadiis vivebat musicus oris, & 
        vicina quondam late celebratus in urbe 
    \& 
    \endnumbering
\end{Rightside} 
\Pages 
\end{pages} 
\end{document}
```

Is there any way to instert extra space between stanzas in parallel-mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to include the material to be inserted between the stanzas into a seperate `\pstart ... \pend` construct, otherwise it won't be processed by the delayed output routine of [`ledpar`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ledpar). So you'll have to replace

```
\newcommand*{\startstanzahook}{\vspace{\baselineskip}}
```

by

```
\def\endstanzaextra{\pstart\skipnumbering\strut\pend}
```

in order to add one extra line between the stanzas (with the `\strut` macro). Note that this hook triggers at the *end* of each stanza, not at the beginning. This is because the extra line is included in the line numbering by default - in order to avoid this, `\skipnumbering` is called, which is only possible at the end of the stanza.

Comment: Thank you very much! That works. I wonder why something like that isn’t mentioned in the manual—or did I overlook something?

Comment: @Tobi Well, I found this solution with the help of example A.3 (p. 82-86) in the [ledpar manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ledmac/ledpar.pdf) where `\endstanzaextra` is used in order to insert a dash between the stanzas. I fear, however, that you can only find it there if you're explicitly looking for it... It would be worth mentioning it directly, especially because the trouble with `ledpar` is that you never know which features of `ledmac` still work and which don't.